# SFML 2.0 crashes when Clock::getElapsedTime() is called

Tags: c++, c, sfml

This code makes the program freeze ("Game.exe has stopped working"):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

int main()
{

    sf::Clock clock;
    clock.getElapsedTime();

    return 0;
}
```

**However, this doesn't crash:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

int main()
{

    sf::Clock clock;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using SFML 2.0, Windows 7, MinGW 4.70 (Code::Blocks). I don't know why, I followed all instructions to link the libraries and nothing seems to be working.

I might be missing something simple through my anger (I've been trying to run sample code for a week, nothing has been working), so can anybody throw me a bone?

**Other details:**

- Linking to the -d libraries didn't help
- I have all .dll's in the same directory as the .exe
- Debug and Release mode don't help
- I have the application set to "GUI Application," and "Console Application" doesn't work either

**GDB Spits out a seg. fault:**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In sf::Clock::Clock() () (C:\Users\kworden\Documents\Work\Programming\Game\bin\Debug\sfml-system-2.dll)
At C:\Users\kworden\Documents\Work\Programming\Game\main.cpp:8
```

***SOLUTION:***

Compile the libraries yourself. I used the tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1zN_QRSwxw) and relinked to the libs generated by CMake.

Comment: Does it happen with any SFML function, just `getElapsedTime` or just `Clock` functions?

Comment: Everything else fails. RenderWindow fails at the ctor.

Comment: Have you tried `gdb`? If so, what did it report?

Comment: I googled this just to see what this lib was an all indications are that you need to recompile the lib:

http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=8726.0

Comment: I updated the post to show what GDB shows and will try to compile the libs now.

Comment: I rebuilt the libs and put the solution in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Ken I added the answer from the comment just for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comment:

I googled this just to see what this lib was an all indications are that you need to recompile the lib: [en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=8726.0](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=8726.0)

This did fix the issue.